# How to stop other website to send cross domain ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, security, cors

From 2 different applications, I was able to send cross-orgin requests. Though the browser return an error of Cross-Origin, but my server is still receiving and executing the request. For example, from a remote site, I can invoke cross-domain request using,

```
$.ajax({
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        data:{ my: 'a' },
        url: 'http://MyApp/Page',
        type: 'POST'
})
```

I know that the browser does not return the response to script, but my server page still execute.

Let's say a innocent user is logged-in a site, http://abc.com. This application will accept post request to insert a record. When  innocent user visits to innocent http://HackerSite.com, the http://HackerSite.com will be able to send a POST request to http://abc.com via Ajax. How to avoid this?

Comment: Nice question. If you have answer for that i will appreciate a lot if you post if.

Comment: For a WCF service, you can set **crossdomainscriptaccessenabled** to false in your end point configuration.

Comment: You will have the same problem with a form submit, no javascript involved.  The CORS spec wasn't created with additional security in mind.  Instead, it allows for you to essentially perform the same actions you could already perform (cross-origin) sans ajax.  The CORS spec goes a bit farther, in that it ensure your server doesn't even receive the underlying request, if your server doesn't properly opt-in to the spec and the same request could not be sent cross-origin sans ajax (say, via a form submit).  This last concept is called preflighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vulnerability you are talking about is [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) but it can be guarded against.

You can guard against the POST being submitted outside of an AJAX request (e.g. by a HTML form) by sending and checking the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header. This also cannot be sent cross-domain via AJAX due to this header not being in the safe list (without [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) that is).

However in the past there have been some exploits via plugins such as flash where headers could be set that were not possible via a browser (e.g. `Referer`) so to guard against this it is recommended to use the [synchroniser token pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) which involves setting a token in a hidden field which will be validated as well as cookies for all destructive requests. By destructive I mean requests that change, submit or delete things (i.e. what should be POSTs).

For more info see here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: In my asp.net web-form case, it's sending the cookie, Here are rules of preflight, `The browser can skip the preflight request if the following conditions are true:

    The request method is GET, HEAD, or POST, and
    The application does not set any request headers other than Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, or Last-Event-ID, and
    The Content-Type header (if set) is one of the following:
        application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        multipart/form-data
        text/plain
`

Comment: But I will check again and you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On easy solution but that is not totally bulletproof is what we call a "validation token". Every post coming from your website should have a CSRF Token that you validate on the server side to make sure the request really comes from your website.  Check this for more information: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be set appropriately to disallow the domains other than the ones you require. however this works only for modern browsers. 
refer http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/
http://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/CrossOriginRequestSecurity

Comment: This is not the proper place to implement security. The browser/client cannot be trusted.